# UITableView - how do I close row actions?

Tags: uitableview

I've implemented `tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:`. In response to some of these actions, i want to snap the row action area back closed.

There doesn't seem to be an appropriate method on `UITableViewRowAction`. I've tried `endEditing` on both the table and table cell; I'm not sure what to try next.

How do I do snap the action area closed?

Comment: Hi Steven, did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Not one that was workable. A friend has been reloading the cell by index path, but I couldn't live with the visuals of that. Instead, I removed row actions from the one screen in my app that this affected. Let me know if you find something that works.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To close the edit actions you can either set the tableViews edit state:

```
tableView.editing = NO
```

or set it with animation:

```
[tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES]
```

Answer (score 8):

> Update for Swift 3

I've been looking for a way to do this using Swift 3, and I finally found it:

```
tableView.isEditing = false
```

Answer (score 5):

If you do `self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)`, the user will be brought out of editing mode. I think what you want is you want to stay in editing mode but just dismissing the row action. So you can use the following code:

`self.tableView.cellForRow(at: cellIndex)?.setEditing(false, animated: true)
self.tableView.reloadData() // this is necessary, otherwise, it won't animate`